# Wordpress dashboard filter based on fields URL 404 check

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site with hundreds of posts, each with an image URL stored in a custom field called `fulllimage`. These URLs are either images on the Instagram CDN or thumbnails on the Youtube CDN. Every now and then, some of the URLs expire or people are deleting the corresponding content directly from these platforms.

I need a way, to filter out the affected posts in the Wordpress admin panel to be able to bulk trash/delete them. I already created custom filters before using `restrict_manage_posts` but afaik, this method is just creating a query to check a certain field or taxonomy value.

I did something like this in the past to filter based on a `network`-field dropdown.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts',[$this, 'filter_posts_by_network']);

public function filter_posts_by_network($query) {       
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $scr = get_current_screen();
        if ($scr->base === 'edit' && in_array($scr->post_type, $this->cpts, true)) {
            if (isset($_GET['network']) && $_GET['network'] != 'all') {
                $query->set('meta_query', array( array(
                    'key' => 'network',
                    'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['network'])
                ) ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My guess would be, to loop over all the entries and check wether the URL in the fullimage field is returning a 404 or not and then, somehow tell the list to update. But i need a hint on how to approach this or if there is even a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Flow wise I would go for something like this:

Either Cronjob, or on visiting of the Editor page (Gutenberg)

#### Cronjob

I prefer Cronjobs over doing your checks on-load as that might interfere with the user experience. Either way:

- Periodically run a script that checks only those fields in the database containing the URL's.
- Merge those results into a link table. You can use Core functions for that.
  See [Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) on the WordPress Codex for more information.
- Run another Cronjob periodically (at night or something) to checks those URL's. Flag URL's that respond a 404.
- Run another (or within the same job/method) Cronjob that validates URL's in your WordPress Posts table, to those in the link table. Proces those URL's/fields how you want to. Emptying the field or something else.

#### Onload

This might be more effective in the short run, but that depends on how many times the user visits the Editor for `pre_get_posts` to run.

on the `pre_get_posts` hook or the [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook:

- Get the URL from the field
- AJAX check the URL's response
- Flag the field or proces the data how you like
- Report back to User

  - You could use the notification API.

The main problem I see with this approach is if a user quickly wants to make a small edit and the script can't finish correctly. but then again, you could catch that event via JS. To easily solve this problem, change the hook from `init`, to `save_post`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I thought of a Cronjob as well, but there's a problem with that. Let's say Youtube is changing all of its CDN URLs so every single URL i stored would be invalid. If this is the case, i'd need to refetch the new URLs first instead of letting a Cronjob delete every single post. So that's not an option. It needs to be done by a Wordpress admin manually.

Comment: That's why I opted for a flag, I don't like deleting data either :P.
A solution to that, would be to export the video ID for the youtube URL's. I don't think Alphabet will change those any time soon so that's not a risk factor.

Comment: The Onload & JS suggestion is also problematic. I don't want to run this every time the user visits the list in the dashboard. I thought there is a way to run this only if they click on "filter" using the given UI. Another option would be to do it entirely custom using the Wordpress Rest API but i'd prefer a simple PHP function.

Comment: One thing is certain, this won't be a simple PHP function since you want to validate and check the data before processing it. If you want really simple, then you just could use `file_get_contents()` to check the URL every time the field gets saved via [`pre_{field}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_field/)

Comment: Ah i see, but that wouldn't work if i need to check like 1000 posts once a week right? I would need to save all of them again to trigger the check.

Comment: No, that would mean an User/Admin would have to visit/edit 1000 posts a week.
I think a Cronjob is really the way to go. The Cronjob however doesnt _have_ to be complex. It could be just a PHP file with `file_get_contents()`. but that's your decision.

Comment: I mean on the list page. Not on the detail page of each post. My goal is to have a filter on the post listing to get only affected posts when i hit the "filter" button. Then, an admin/editor could easily bulk delete them using the default Wordpress UI.

Comment: That why I explicitly used Editor instead of Admin page. To avoid an extended discussion: with the information I've given, you should have enough _hints_ by now.